# How does one add an import statement to a anltr4 generated java parser for use of a class in a semantic predicate

Tags: java, import, package, antlr4

I have a antlr4 grammar that I want to call a function in which another Java class in a semantic predicate.  How do I tell antlr4 to add the appropriate import statement to the class, so that it can find the class I want to use?

Here is a fragment of antlr4 code showing a predicate using a class like I want.  Note the call to OtherClass in the semantic predicate.

```
   somerule : { OtherClass.test(_input.LT(1).getText()) }? Token
```

How do I tell antlr4 to add the following import statement to the top of the generated parser?

```
import my.otherpackage.OtherClass;
```

I suppose I could add to the directory where antlr4 writes the generated parser a "forwarding" class like this, but it seems a hack

```
package  GeneratedParser;

import my.otherpackage.OtherClass;

class OtherClassForParser {

   public Boolean test(String text) {
      return OtherClass.test(text);
   }
}
```

Then in antlr4 rewrite it to use

```
   somerule : { OtherClassForParser.test(_input.LT(1).getText()) }? Token
```

That will probably work because the forwarding class would then be in the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@parser::header{
   import my.otherpackage.OtherClass;
}
```

(Usually toward the top of your grammar)

Comment: Worked perfectly (once I stopped making typos).  Thanks.